# a setInterval within a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, setinterval

My code below needs to put in a setInterval within a for loop. I basically need to put in a 10 second pause between the next iteration of the for loop. This is for a very basic script which shows banners in a div for 10 seconds before moving onto the next one. It existing setInterval is code I got off another website as I ran out of options. Any help? And if you don't mind explaining the logic to me so that I know for the future :)

```
$("document").ready(function() {

// bannerChange
function bannerChange(banner,div,milliseconds) {
    var length = banner.length;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
        (function(i) {
            setInterval(function() {
                var url = banners[i].url;
                var img = banners[i].image;
                $("#"+div).html("<a href='"+url+"' target='_Blank'><img src='www/images/banners/"+img+"' /></a>");
            },milliseconds)
        })(i);
    }
}

function showBanner(bannerName, bannerDiv, milliseconds) {
    var url = "www/scripts/ajax/getBanners.php";
    $.post(url, {name: bannerName}, function(data) {
        if(data.response == true) {
            bannerChange(data.banners,bannerDiv,milliseconds);
        }
    });
}

// Run banners
showBanner("Test Banner","test",10000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an updated version based on the comment:

```
// Start by getting the banners:

var banners = [];
var currentBanner;

function getBannersFromServer(...) {
    // TODO: make ajax call to server for banners

    // push the banners into a queue for later
    for (var i in bannerFromServer) {
        banners.push(bannersFromServer[i]);
    }
}

// Then run through them:

function showNextBanner() {
    // advance to next banner
    currentBanner++

    // go back to the beginning after the last banner is displayed
    if(currentBanner >= banners.length) currentBanner = 0;

    // pull a banner out of the queue
    var banner = banners[currentBanner];

    // TODO: Show the banner in the div

    // do it again in 10 seconds
    showNextBanner();
}

// start it all
getBannersFromServer();
getNextBanner();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My only issue is that I am getting a json array from the server with the banners associated with that specific banner name, so, I wont be getting new banners from the server. Thats why I figured a) get banners b) run a for loop and then c) somehow pause iterations for 10 seconds. I'm not sure if your example above will do this?

Comment: Hi Ariel, thanks again for your reply. You're example above is perfect, but my lack of proper js is letting me down :) I am pulling toe records from the server and pushing it into the banners array. These records appears to be json. I did a console.log(banners) within getNextBanner(). The response appears to be a multi-dimensional array banners[][0] = json object, banners[][1] = json object ect. Whats weird is that if I do the var banner = banners[currentBanner] and console.log(banner) I get undefined. even if I try console.log(banner[0]) the same story. Any advise?

Comment: Ariel, sorry, I think I know what the issue is. I have the for loop as above within my $.post(), so effectively I cannot use banners as a different property outside of the $.post() function. I have never retrieved info from a server using $.post() and used it in other functions, is that even possible?

Comment: Got it to work! I moved the getNextBanner() within the $.post() and also created an interval straight after that, so it runs the function once and then sets an interval to run the function each 10 seconds. Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
.delay()
```

[Here is a great example of this function in use!](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: `.delay()` was designed for animations. it shouldn't really be used to delay execution of functions...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var i=0;//Global Variable

function bannerChange(banner, div, milliseconds) {
    var length = banner.length;

    setInterval(function() {
        var url = banners[i].url;
        var img = banners[i].image;

        $("#"+div).html("<a href='"+url+"' target='_Blank'><img src='www/images/banners/"+img+"' /></a>");

        i++;
        if(i >= length) i=0;//To reiterate from first
    },milliseconds);            
 }
```

Hope this solves your problem.